# C++ XMPP library that supports xep-0234(jingle)

Tags: c++, xmpp, libjingle

I'm looking for well-documented and easy-to-use XMPP library that supports 
Jingle file transfer. Must work under Windows. Preferably for C++, but if you believe that there is a libray in other languages (C, Python,...) that is much better than any library written in C++ - please let me know)

Thank  you!

Comment: Have you had a look at libJingle: http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/ ?

Answer (score 0):

[Swiften](http://swift.im/swiften/) is a modern cross platform C++ XMPP library which powers the [Swift](http://swift.im/) XMPP client.  It has support for Jingle file transfer.

Comment: thank you. Can you compare it with other XMPP libraries? Gloox, for example? I found some in http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/ - but some of them aren't maintained, some of them lack support of various features, etc...

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with either.  I recommend Swiften more based on project health and the crankiness of its users.  I can't say that I've heard much good about gloox, but I know a few projects that have switched away from it.  One of them, spectrum, has switched to Swiften.